# 14 The fastest way to insert text data into mongodb

Tags: mongodb, performance, xslt, import

I have very large xml file and want to insert it into mongodb. I can use xsltproc to transform this file to any text format (json, csv, etc) and this is pretty fast.  But how can I insert this file into mongodb?

Statistic on example file of 61 MB:

```
mongoimport json  :  52 seconds  
mongoimport csv   :  14 seconds  (only -f works not --headerline)
```

Is there any faster way?

upd:  compared with postgresql COPY  -  8 seconds.

Comment: are you going to store full file as is without any processing?

Comment: The file contains many records, I will not insert the whole file in one collection item :)